# Как сделать Ютуб ссылку аудиоссылкой и по ней воспроизводить аудио. Возможно ли вообще такое?

Tags: javascript, youtube

У меня есть аудио проигрыватель на сайте стилизованный, где пользователь берет аудиофайл с компьютера и запускает его. Возможно ли так сделать, чтобы пользователь вставлял ссылку с ютуба и без всяких сторонних программ, где скачиваешь, потом преобразовываешь запускал звук с ютуб страницы в моем плеере?

Comment: Да, возможно. Берите с ютуба весь ролик, а пользователю включайте только звук из него.

Comment: А как это делается? Если через ПОДЕЛИТЬСЯ беру Iframe и вставляю куском кода вот так <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_aEKgMmLiP8" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen> А как это в плеер загнать, там у меня отдельные кнопки воспроизведения последние 2, 5, 10 секунд, название отобразить?

Comment: Теоретически, можно скрыть фрейм, а через контролзы в вашем плеере управлять воспроизведением видео из этого скрытого фрейма. Практически - есть api для подгрузки полной инфы по видео с ютуба, в том числе и ссылки на скачивание в разных форматах (причем, конвертация на бекенде не происходит), но то, что нашел, платное - https://rapidapi.com/ehmo/api/SaveDeo